# Check for distinct values in a row - sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Given a table with columns (col1,col2,col3,col4,....) , how do we query the table such that it returns only the rows where a specific subset of columns, for example (col2,col4,col5) have values different from each other.

For example for this table(this table is generated after performing some cross-joins and querying), define subset of columns as (t1_id, t2_id, t3_id):

[image]

The query should then return this:

[image]

The subset of columns will be variable and can be very large hence using sth like `where t1.id<>t2.id and t1.id<>t3.id and t2.id<>t3.id` wouldn't be a handy approach.

Comment: We can, and should, reject the premise of the question. In a normalised environment - the kind of environment upon which an RDBMS thrives - such a situation wouldn't occur

Comment: @Strawberry the id field is not primary key so this situation can and does exist. I guess I used a bad name here.

Comment: No. Normalise your schema

Comment: The schema is normalized. The current table is generated after some cross-joins. I  will edit the description.

Comment: Ah, that's very different - but then the JOINs themselves could handle the filtering

Comment: What database are you using?  MySQL and PL/SQL are two very different things.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution could be to use NOT IN criteria for N-1 columns.
Which can be shortened for each additional NOT IN.

For example if there are 5 columns :

```
WHERE t1.id NOT IN (t5.id, t4.id, t3.id, t2.id)
  AND t2.id NOT IN (t5.id, t4.id, t3.id)
  AND t3.id NOT IN (t5.id, t4.id)
  AND t4.id <> t5.id
```

Another method is to concat the id's and then use a regex.

```
-- test table with numbers 
create table test (id int primary key);
insert into test values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

-- cross joining the numbers and only get those with unique number combinations 
select t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2, t3.id as id3, t4.id as id4, t5.id as id5
from test t1 
cross join test t2 
cross join test t3 
cross join test t4
cross join test t5
where concat_ws(' ',t1.id,t2.id,t3.id,t4.id,t5.id) not rlike '\\b(\\d+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b';
```

Tested on  [dbfiddle for MariaDb 10.2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2)

Comment: I had this idea from your previous answer, however I was wondering if there is a more general approach.
Because I will be doing this on a variable input of columns, so lets say if the subset of columns could be between [2,n], I would need to generate (n-1) such if clauses, and in each clause have similar "where" clauses. Too much mess i think.

Comment: How large could that N be? If it's for those cross joins in your previous question? How many cross joins do you think are possible till the database chokes?  Btw, are you looking for a standard ANSI SQL solution, or just Oracle?

Comment: Well in my situation its only between [2-7] so its doable however I was still wondering if there was a generalized way. Like we can check for distinct columns easily so any similar thing. I am looking for a mysql way.

Comment: @nazschi MySql 5.x or 8.x ? Because in 8.x you could do something with a REGEXP_LIKE. But in 5.x the regex engine uses POSIX ERE, which doesn't support back references. So a regex like `([0-9]+).*\1` isn't usable in 5.x

Comment: I have this: 10.1.31-MariaDB
Using mysql on phpmyadmin

Comment: @valarmorghulis I can't find a free online test database for MariaDB online. So can you test the following for me? `create table test (id int primary key);
insert into test values (1),(2),(3);
select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id
from test t1
cross join test t2
cross join test t3
where concat(',',t1.id,',',t2.id,',',t3.id,',') not RLIKE '\\b(\\d+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b';`. I think it uses [PCRE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pcre/), and needs double backslashes. But can't test it.

Comment: the queries ran. The result was all 6 possible combinations of (1,2,3). But that wasnt the question though.

Comment: Well, just trying to figure out what regex would work.  Did you try with `NOT RLIKE '\\b(\\d+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b'` ?  I had changed my comment later after going through the MariaDB documentation.

Comment: It's quite annoying that I can't test it myself... And I'm not willing to install a such RDBMS on my laptop.  And none of the online database test sites seem to have a MariaDB. Oh well...  Maybe someone else will find another solution.

Comment: its okay. Thank you for your inputs. Lets see if someone comes up with something else.

Comment: @valarmorghulis I found an online tester for MariaDb after all.  See updated answer. But that one uses 10.2.  So maybe it won't work for your 10.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

The `not in` approach makes the most sense to me.

However, [MariaDB supports PCRE regular expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pcre/#absolute-and-relative-numeric-backreferences).  And these support back references.  So you can use them to look for duplicates:

```
where concat(',', concat_ws(',', t1.id, t2.id, t3.id), ',') not regexp '([^,]+).*,\1,'
```

Note that you might have to double up on the backslash, because it is often an escape character.